# Add a job step in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a questions about creating a SQL Job. Can somebody please let me know that how we can
add a job step in the middle. Like if I want to add a step between step 2 and step 3. I would really apprecaite it.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of SQL Server (is it even MS SQL Server)? Are you using SSMS to manage your jobs?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to SQL Server Agent
2. find the job that you want to modify and right-click and select Properties.
3. Under Steps, add a new step, put in what you need to do then OK to confirm.
4. Then order the steps and OK to confirm.